# How can I use 32bit color depth image to convert to pcd or ply with PCL

Tags: opencv, depth, hololens, ply-file-format

I try to get a point cloud using a 32bit color depth image from Hololens, But I am having a hard time because I do not have much information about it. Do I have to have camera parameters to get point clouds from the depth image? Is there a way to convert from PCL or OpenCV?

I add some comment and picture. Finally I can get the point cloud using depth image from hololens. But I convert 32bit depth image to grayscale and feel that the sensors of the lens alone have a lot of distortion. To complement this, I think we need to find a way to undistortion and filtering the depth image.

Do you have any other information about this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To get a point cloud through a depth image, you need focal-length, center.x, and center.y information. Since the depth image is a form of the final result of the depth data, I do not think I should care much about the min and max values. For reference, the resolution of the hololens sensor is 448x450 and x and y are 224 and 225. Refer to the link for how to get the sensor values https://mtaulty.com/2018/06/19/sketchy-experiments-with-hololens-facial-tracking-research-mode-rgb-streams-depth-streams/